# How can i get Map API key from backend API using fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, dynamic, fragment

Hello guys i am using fragment for map and i am put my map key in Manifest.xml. now i am trying to get Map API from backend API which made in PHP and put into my code and map will work.

Here is my code :-

**Layout**

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        tools:layout="@layout/dummy_map" />
```

**ManiFest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_map_key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change strings.xml dynamically since it's a compiled resource. There are other mechanisms for saving data in Android, here's a nice post that covers Data Storage. Hope this helps [check](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

this is not possible in Google API V2. The documentation suggest the same thing, the API key has to be assigned using the Manifest file:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#adding_the_api_key_to_your_application